# Распознавание эмоций на сайте с помощью Python

Tags: python, веб-программирование, нейронные-сети

Моя задача — создать простой сайт с функцией распознавания эмоций через веб-камеру. Для этого я выбрал [этот проект](https://github.com/oarriaga/face_classification). Как я могу встроить программу на Python в код веб-страницы, чтобы она выполнялась по нажатию кнопки, например? Сам в Python ничего не понимаю, но читал, что может пригодиться Flask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Питон на страницу браузера не встроить никак. Для решения описанной задачи Вам нужно разработать веб-приложение (можно простейшее одностраничное на том же Фласке), которое будет выдавать страницу браузеру. Затем на ней по нажатию кнопки JavaScript'ом обращаться к камере, получать изображение, отправлять его на сервер. Далее сервер использует это изображение для классификации, и возвращает ответ клиенту. JavaScript на странице должен получать ответ от сервера и отображать его пользователю.

Если для Вас это слишком сложно (что следует из вопроса), то учите основы и разрабатывайте отдельные элементы нужного функционала:

- Вводная часть:

  - [Википедия: клиент-сервер](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82_%E2%80%94_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80)
  - [Хабр: Клиент-серверная архитектура](https://habr.com/ru/post/495698/)
- Python сервер:

  - [Официальная документация Flask (eng)](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/)
  - [ВикиУчебник: Flask](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/Flask)
- JS:

  - [W3School: onclick event in JS](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)
  - [MDN: JavaScript AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) либо [Хабр: JavaScript + jQuery AJAX](https://habr.com/ru/post/42426/)
  - [MDN: Работа с камерой](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Taking_still_photos)

Если это всё осилите, то дальше справитесь самостоятельно